# Is this a good way to use strcpy?

Tags: c, strcpy

I try to use `strcpy`; is it a good way to do so?

```
char *stringvar;
stringvar = malloc(strlen("mi string") + 1);
strcpy(stringvar, "mi string");
stringvar[strlen("mi string")] = '\0';
```

What do you think?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about reviewing a working code

Comment: review no, i ask good way

Comment: that is a review

Comment: Code review is for questions that are about "tell me how to improve this blob of code" . This question is not off-topic on Stack Overflow because it asks if a way is good or not. It is not opinionated either, because the answer is unequivocally "No, this is not a good way. In fact you needn't use `strcpy` for this at all."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the last line

```
stringvar[strlen("mi string")] = '\0';
```

`strcpy` takes care of that for you.

In real code you absolutely must check `malloc`'s return value to make sure it's not `NULL`.

Other than that your code is fine.  In particular, you've got the vital `+ 1` in the call to `malloc`.  `strlen` gives you the length of the string *not* including the terminating `'\0'` character, but `strcpy` is going to add it, so you absolutely need to allocate space for it.

The problem with `strcpy` -- the fatal problem, some people say -- is that at the moment you call `strcpy`, you have no way of telling `strcpy` how big the destination array is.  It's *your responsibility* to make the array big enough, and avoid overflow.  `strcpy` is unable, by itself, to prevent buffer overflow -- and of course if the destination does overflow, that's a big problem.

So then the question is, how can you ensure -- absolutely *ensure* -- that all the calls to `strcpy` in all the code you write are correct?  And how can you ensure that later, someone modifying your program won't accidentally mess things up?

Basically, if you use `strcpy` at all, you want to arrange that two things are right next to each other:

1. the code that arranges that the pointer variable points to enough space for the string you're about to copy into it, and
2. the actual call to `strcpy` that copies the string into that pointer.

So your code

```
stringvar = malloc(strlen("mi string") + 1);
strcpy(stringvar, "mi string");
```

comes pretty close to that ideal.

I know your code is only an example, but it does let us explore the concern, what if later, someone modifying your program accidentally messes things up?  What if someone changes it to

```
stringvar = malloc(strlen("mi string") + 1);
strcpy(stringvar, "mi string asombroso");
```

Obviously we've got a problem.  So to make *absolutely sure* that there's room for the string we're copying, it's even better, I think, if the string we're copying is in a variable, so it's patently obvious that the string we're copying is the *same* string we allocated space for.

So here's my improved version of your code:

```
char *inputstring = "mi string";
char *stringvar = malloc(strlen(inputstring) + 1);
if(stringvar == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
strcpy(stringvar, inputstring);
```

(Unfortunately, the check for a `NULL` return from `malloc` gets in the way of the goal of having the `strcpy` call right next to the `malloc` call.)

Basically your code is an implementation of the C library function [`strdup`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup), which takes a string you give it and returns a copy in `malloc`'ed memory.

One more thing.  You were worried about the `+ 1` in the all to `malloc`, and as I said, it's correct.  A pretty common error is

```
stringvar = malloc(strlen(inputstring));
strcpy(stringvar, inputstring);
```

This fails to allocate space for the `\0`, so when `strcpy` adds the `\0` it overflows the allocated space, so it's a problem.

And with that said, make sure you don't accidentally write

```
stringvar = malloc(strlen("mi string" + 1));
```

Do you see the error?  This is a surprisingly easy mistake to make, but obviously it doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: You surely don't want to declare (and then use) `char inputstring = "mi string"`, even if it probably compiles ;-).

Comment: i read post other, say it strlen("mi string") == 9 + '\0', is strlen say 10 or 9?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I surely didn't.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, it still should be const, and the line should end with a semicolon... I learned the hard way not to post un-run (let alone un-compiled) code...

Comment: @Roman `strlen` returns the length of the characters in the string, *not* counting the `'\0'`.  so `strlen("mi string")` is 9, not 10.

Comment: i ask need + 1 in malloc?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I learned that lesson a long time ago, too.  Trouble is, sometimes I still cheat... :-(

Comment: @Roman Yes, you do.

Comment: @Roman indeed, it is needed. Omitting it is a common and fatal error.

Answer (score 5):

There is exactly one bug in it: You don't check for malloc-failure.

Aside from that, it's repetitive and error-prone.
And overwriting the terminator with the terminator is useless.
Also, the repeated recalculation of the string-length is expensive.
Anyway, as you already have to determine the length, prefer [`memcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) over [`strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

What you should do is extracting it into a function, let's call it [`strdup()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) (that is the name POSIX and the next C standard give it):

```
char* strdup(const char* s) {
    size_t n = strlen(s) + 1;
    char* r = malloc(n);
    if (r)
        memcpy(r, s, n);
    return r;
}

char* stringvar = strdup("mi string");
if (!stringvar)
    handle_error();
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some issues with the code posted:

- you do not check if `malloc()` succeeded: if `malloc()` fails and returns `NULL`, passing this null pointer to `strcpy` has undefined behavior.
- the last statement `stringvar[strlen("mi string")] = '\0';` is useless: `strcpy` **does** copy the null terminator at the end of the source string, making the destination array a proper C string.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
...
    char *stringvar;
    if ((stringvar = malloc(strlen("mi string") + 1)) != NULL)
        strcpy(stringvar, "mi string");
```

Note that is would be slightly better to store the allocation size and not use `strcpy`:

```c
    char *stringvar;
    size_t size = strlen("mi string") + 1;
    if ((stringvar = malloc(size)) != NULL)
        memcpy(stringvar, "mi string", size);
```

Indeed it would be even simpler and safer to use `strdup()`, available on POSIX compliant systems, that performs exactly the above steps:

```c
    char *stringvar = strdup("mi string");
```